# Is there any signifiance in Lex Luthor being a Liberace fan?

Tags: dc, superman, lex-luthor, superman-2

In the Richard Donner cut of *Superman II*, Lex Luthor wants his Liberace record back from an inmate who borrowed it.

Is this a subtle humorous reference to prison homosexuality? Or a commentary on Luthor's sexuality?

Comment: Lex Luthor likes to listen to Liberace. Maybe he just enjoys the alliteration.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Lois Lane, Lana Lang, Lex Luthor... always actively avoid alliteration, eh?

Comment: Pretty sure he didn;t keep Miss Teschmacher around for her secretarial skills. That said, I suppose she could've been a beard....